# Is there a way to use mysqldump without a shell session?

Tags: mysql

I'd like to use mysqldump to back up my database and have written a script to do this by dropping into a shell and issuing a mysqldump statement. Is there a way to get the same dump but without using a shell? Isn't there a way I can use straight SQL to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the raw data into an outfile (using [SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)), but I don't believe there's a way of doing a full 'schema with inserts' style dump.

Comment: Ok.. that's what I figured. Let me ask you another question. I have had bad experiences in the past with csv files not loading the data properly. I have never had that sort of experience using a dump file which was why I decided to go the route I went. Do you have any preference between the two methods?

Comment: It depends what you want it data for - if it's for backup purposes, I always go the dump file route.

Comment: Yeah, these will be backups. I'd have to agree with you. I'll stick with the mysqldump. Thanks.